# Unknown Errors in Program

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm very new to C, and come from a Java background, and I'm having trouble debugging these functions I made. Basically, the idea is they will be passed a word, create a node for a linked list and then insert sort the new node into the linked list. I don't understand what my mistakes are in the code and I am having trouble finding out how to fix them. If anyone could help steer me down the right path on this, I would really appreciate the help! Thank you all in advance! Please find the code for my functions below.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Node record
struct node {
char data;
struct node* next;
}; 



//insertion sorting (will sort as inserted)
void insert_dictionary_order(struct node** head_ref, char word)
{ 
   struct node* temp; 
   struct node* new_node; 
       new_node->data = word; 
       
   //If new insert is before head, put current head next, and set head to new node
   if (*head_ref == NULL || strcmp((*head_ref)->data, new_node->data) > 0)  //if new_node comes before this 
   {
       new_node->next=*head_ref; 
       *head_ref = new_node;
   } 
   else
   { 
       //find the node before insertion point 
       temp = *head_ref; 
       while(current->next != NULL && current->next->data < new_node->data) 
       { 
            current = current->next;
       } 
       new_node->next = next; 
       current->next = new_node;
   }
    
}



//function to print list by being passed head
void print_list(struct node *head) 
{ 
    Struct node *temp = head; 
    while(temp != NULL) 
    { 
        printf("%s\n", temp->data); 
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

And here are the errors I am receiving:

```
17899186/source.c: In function ‘insert_dictionary_order’:
17899186/source.c:21:36: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    if (*head_ref == NULL || strcmp((*head_ref)->data, new_node->data) > 0)  //if new_node comes before this
                                    ^
In file included from 17899186/source.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:136:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
            ^~~~~~
17899186/source.c:21:55: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    if (*head_ref == NULL || strcmp((*head_ref)->data, new_node->data) > 0)  //if new_node comes before this
                                                       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from 17899186/source.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:136:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
            ^~~~~~
17899186/source.c:30:14: error: ‘current’ undeclared (first use in this function)
        while(current->next != NULL && current->next->data < new_node->data)
              ^~~~~~~
17899186/source.c:30:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
17899186/source.c:34:25: error: ‘next’ undeclared (first use in this function)
        new_node->next = next;
                         ^~~~
17899186/source.c:16:17: warning: variable ‘temp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    struct node* temp;
                 ^~~~
17899186/source.c: In function ‘print_list’:
17899186/source.c:45:5: error: unknown type name ‘Struct’; did you mean ‘struct’?
     Struct node *temp = head;
     ^~~~~~
     struct
17899186/source.c:45:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
     Struct node *temp = head;
                 ^
17899186/source.c:46:11: error: ‘temp’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘bcmp’?
     while(temp != NULL)
           ^~~~
           bcmp
```

Comment: `strcmp` is used to compare _strings_ not _characters_. Use `==` for comparing characters. "error: unknown type name ‘Struct’; did you mean ‘struct’": The compiler told you the problem and the solution right there.

Comment: @Spikatrix ok, so is there a String type in C like in Java? Because I need to compare entire words in this case, so I have to compare Strings. If there is a String datatype, I'll just change the node data to being a String

Comment: There is no `String` datatype in C. Strings in C are basically character arrays terminated by a NUL-character. So instead of `char data`, you'll need something like `char data[64]`

Comment: @Spikatrix Oh I see! and in this case the number assigned is how many characters each node can store?

Comment: Yes, `data` can store a maximum of 63 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator at the end).

Comment: @Spikatrix Alright, and one more question, sorry for pestering you on this, but if I was to pass in an array of characters like word in this case, how would I do this? Right now I have it as: `void insert_dictionary_order(struct node** head_ref, char *word)
{ 
   struct node* temp; 
   struct node* new_node; 
       new_node->data = *word; `, but I am still receiving the error `94812126/source.c: In function ‘insert_dictionary_order’:
94812126/source.c:18:23: error: assignment to expression with array type
        new_node->data = *word;`

Comment: `new_node->data = *word` is wrong as 1. You can't assign arrays 2. `*word` is a single character (You probably meant `word` there). There's a library function called `strcpy` that helps you to copy strings. You'll need to use it here.

Comment: You are not going to get anywhere trying to learn C by trial and error. Get yourself a good book (or online course) and start at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so lets go through the errors and warnings you get:

- `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`
  `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

  Theses warnings say that `strcmp` expects a pointer but you've passed an integer to it. Even though this is a warning and not and error (It should be an error IMO) you should definitely work on fixing it before proceeding.
- `note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’`

  This is showing the expected and provided types for of arguments for `strcmp`. You passed a `char` variables (`(*head_ref)->data` and `new_node->data`) but `strcmp` expects `const char*`, a pointer to a character (Basically a string in case of `strcmp`)
- `error: ‘current’ undeclared (first use in this function)`
  `error: ‘next’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

  You haven't declared `current` and `next` in this function.
- `warning: variable ‘temp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable] struct node* temp;`

  The variable `temp` was assigned a value but it wasn't used. This is basically reporting unused variables and you can ignore this warning
- `error: unknown type name ‘Struct’; did you mean ‘struct’?`

  Error is self-explanatory and even provides a solution. C is case-sensitive.
- `error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token`
  `error: ‘temp’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘bcmp’?`

  These errors were thrown because of the previous one. These should go away once you fix the typo `Struct` -> `struct`.

You should note that `char data;` can hold a *single* character and not an entire string. If you need to store a string, you'll have to use an array like `char data[64];`. The 64 denotes the size of the array. It means that `data` can store a maximum of 63 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator `\0` at the end). There are ways to make the size dynamic but that's a topic for another day :-)